# Spring Boot recuperação de objetos que contém um outro objeto em seus atributos incorre em erro

Tags: spring-boot

Sou iniciante em Spring Boot e minha aplicação está apresentando o seguinte erro:

```xml
{
    "timestamp": "2021-07-07T02:27:00.231+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->one.digitalinnovation.personapi.dto.request.PersonDTO[\"job\"]->one.digitalinnovation.personapi.entity.Job$HibernateProxy$040pRItT[\"hibernateLazyInitializer\"])\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:460)\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:181)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:853)\nCaused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->one.digitalinnovation.personapi.dto.request.PersonDTO[\"job\"]->one.digitalinnovation.personapi.entity.Job$HibernateProxy$040pRItT[\"hibernateLazyInitializer\"])\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1276)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1510)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1006)\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:454)\n\t... 52 more\n",
    "message": "Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->one.digitalinnovation.personapi.dto.request.PersonDTO[\"job\"]->one.digitalinnovation.personapi.entity.Job$HibernateProxy$040pRItT[\"hibernateLazyInitializer\"])",
    "path": "/api/v1/people"
```

Esse erro ocorre ao tentar listar as pessoas cadastradas!

Acredito que tenha algo a ver com recuperar o objeto Job no objeto Person.

O projeto está estruturado em Entity (Job, Person), Controller(Job, Person), DTO (Job, Person), Service (Job, Person), Mapper - Interface (Job, Person), individualmente as APIS cadastram, exibem todos os itens, buscam pelo id.

Decidi criar um campo do tipo Job em Person e PersonDTO.

Quando cadastro informo o objeto person contendo o job previamente cadastrado por um json, quando salvo e vou olhar na tabela está gravado corretament, mas quando tento recuperar o person ele cai nesse erro.

Código:


`package one.digitalinnovation.personapi.entity;`

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import one.digitalinnovation.personapi.mapear.JobMapper;
import one.digitalinnovation.personapi.service.JobService;
import org.mapstruct.MappingTarget;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String firstName;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String lastName;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String cpf;

private LocalDate birthDate;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
private List<Phone> phones;


@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="id_job",nullable=false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_job"))
private Job job;
```

package one.digitalinnovation.personapi.dto.request;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import one.digitalinnovation.personapi.entity.Job;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.br.CPF;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PersonDTO {

```
private Long id;

@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 2, max= 100)
private String firstName;

@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 2, max = 100)
private String lastName;

@NotEmpty
@CPF
private String cpf;

private String birthDate;

@Valid
@NotEmpty
private List<PhoneDTO> phones;

@Valid
@NotNull
private Job job;
```

}

package one.digitalinnovation.personapi.service;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import one.digitalinnovation.personapi.dto.MessageResponseDTO;
import one.digitalinnovation.personapi.dto.request.JobDTO;
import one.digitalinnovation.personapi.dto.request.PersonDTO;
import one.digitalinnovation.personapi.entity.Job;
import one.digitalinnovation.personapi.entity.Person;
import one.digitalinnovation.personapi.exception.PersonNotFoundException;
import one.digitalinnovation.personapi.mapear.JobMapper;
import one.digitalinnovation.personapi.mapear.PersonMapper;
import one.digitalinnovation.personapi.repository.PersonRepository;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class PersonService {

```
private PersonRepository personRepository;

private final PersonMapper personMapper = PersonMapper.INSTANCE;
public MessageResponseDTO createPerson(PersonDTO personDTO){

    Person personToSaved = personMapper.toModel(personDTO);
    Person savedPerson = personRepository.save((personToSaved));
    return createMessageResponse(savedPerson.getId(), "Create person ID ");
}

public List<PersonDTO> listAll() {
    List<Person> allPeople = personRepository.findAll();
    return allPeople.stream()
            .map(personMapper::toDTO)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public PersonDTO findById(Long id) throws PersonNotFoundException {

    Person person = verifyIfExists(id);
    return personMapper.toDTO(person);
}

public void delete(Long id) throws PersonNotFoundException {
    verifyIfExists(id);
    personRepository.deleteById(id);
}



public MessageResponseDTO updateById(Long id, PersonDTO personDTO) throws PersonNotFoundException {

    verifyIfExists(id);

    Person personToUpdate = personMapper.toModel(personDTO);

    Person updatedPerson = personRepository.save(personToUpdate);
    return createMessageResponse(updatedPerson.getId(), "Updated person ID ");
}

private Person verifyIfExists(Long id) throws PersonNotFoundException {
    return personRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new PersonNotFoundException(id));


}

private MessageResponseDTO createMessageResponse(Long id, String message) {
    return MessageResponseDTO
            .builder()
            .message(message + id)
            .build();
}
```

}

package one.digitalinnovation.personapi.mapear;

import one.digitalinnovation.personapi.dto.request.PersonDTO;
import one.digitalinnovation.personapi.entity.Person;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper
public interface PersonMapper {

```
PersonMapper  INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PersonMapper.class);

@Mapping(target = "birthDate", source = "birthDate", dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy")
Person toModel(PersonDTO personDTO);
PersonDTO toDTO(Person person);
```

}

Comment: Bem vindo! Você poderia postar seu código por favor? Além disso, ao postar, coloque o código em markdown conforme vai aparecer instruções no momento de editar a pergunta.

Comment: @leandro.dev Olá. Obrigado! Fiz as alterações, mas se ficar melhor o código se encontra no meu GitHub [link] (https://github.com/rafaelponte89/api-people-coding). A única diferença do código que postei é o campo do tipo Job em Person e PersonDTO e as anotações desses campos.